# Separate mongo databases for meteor apps

Tags: mongodb, meteor

Say I host ten different meteor apps on one server and mongoDB. The applications have same-named collections, so I want to use separate databases for each one of them.
How would I achieve this ? Exporting MONGO_URL will work for one app only, right?

Comment: Removed useless parts of the question. Improved grammar, punctuation.

Comment: You can use different database connections (using mongointernals) for your collections on the server, but AFAIK, on the client collections are identified by the collection name, so conflicting names pose a problem. You might be able to connect to several back-ends from the clients, but I don't think that maintaining 10 websockets is a viable option.

Answer (score 1):

I assume you have some sort of script to start each meteor application, for instance:

```
#!/bin.bash
cd /path/to/my/app
meteor
```

Then, you can just export the MONGO_URL variable as part of each meteor application's startup script, and each application will run with its own value for the MONGO_URL variable.

With that in mind, the startup script for app1 becomes:

```
#!/bin.bash
cd /path/to/my/app1
export MONGO_URL=mongodb://localhost:27017/app1
meteor
```

and the startup script for app2 is:

```
#!/bin.bash
cd /path/to/my/app2
export MONGO_URL=mongodb://localhost:27017/app2
meteor
```

Side-note: what I said applies even if you don't have startup scripts. If you start your applications by hand in the terminal, you can just do:

```
> cd /path/to/my/app1
> export MONGO_URL=mongodb://localhost:27017/app1
> meteor &
> ...
> cd /path/to/my/app2
> export MONGO_URL=mongodb://localhost:27017/app2
> meteor &
```

Comment: If you don't use a script you can type "MONGO_URL=mongodb://localhost:27017/app1 meteor"

Comment: So if I undarstand correctly, after exported settings get picked up by app I can change env var to whatever I want. What in the case of application crash?